# How to disable the particular "Detail Panel" in material-table (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, material-table

> I would like to disable the particular row detail panel in material-table

Sample code below:

```
    function OneDetailPanel() {
      return (
        <MaterialTable
          title="One Detail Panel Preview"
          columns={[
            { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
            { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
            { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
            {
              title: 'Birth Place',
              field: 'birthCity',
              lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
            },
          ]}
          data={[
            { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
            { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
          ]}
          detailPanel={rowData => {
            return (
              <iframe
                width="100%"
                height="315"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c"
                frameborder="0"
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                allowfullscreen
              />
            )
          }}
        />
      )
    }
```

Screen shot:
[image: Detail panel]

> Expected output:

I want to disable the first row details panel.